# Failing on String from .txt file into array of String insertion

Tags: java, foreach, java.util.scanner

This is supposed to be very easy. When I code this I was like 100% sure it will work. I want to create a 2 dimensional array of Strings (data[][]) contains the data of the data.txt and also a 1 dimensional array (kolom[]) contains the column description which is the first line of data.txt.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Data {
private String[][] data;
private String[] kolom;
    public Data() throws FileNotFoundException {
        data = new String[300][4];
        kolom = new String[4];
        Scanner readLine = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));
        Scanner readText = new Scanner(readLine.nextLine()).useDelimiter(";");

        for(String element : kolom) 
            element = readText.next();

        for(String[] row : data) {
            readText = new Scanner(readLine.nextLine()).useDelimiter(";");
            for(String element : row){
                element = readText.next();
            }
        }
    }
    public String[] getKolom() {
        return kolom;
    }
    public String[][] getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException  {
        Data data = new Data();
        for(String element : data.getKolom()) 
            System.out.print(element);
        for(String[] row : data.getData()) 
            for(String element : row)
                System.out.print(element);
    }
}
```

this program outputs all nulls. Which imply the Strings did not inserted into the array.
What are things causing this problem?

- data.txt snippet below(few lines of 301 lines).
- the data.txt is in the same folder with the Data.class file.
- tried changing the enhanced loop into normal loop still same failure.
- is something wrong with the scanner implementation on this?

data.txt

```
Nama;Tanggal;Email;Negara
Kamal;16/04/15;consectetuer.adipiscing@volutpatornarefacilisis.org;Cook Islands
Melodie;15/12/23;Donec@malesuada.co.uk;Gibraltar
Salvador;15/07/01;purus@bibendum.edu;Lesotho
Garth;14/02/02;pede.Nunc.sed@faucibusid.org;Namibia
```

ps: 'kolom' is 'column', in my native language

Comment: Don't you think it's odd to iterate over the buffer, you should try using `hasNext()` on you scanners and a while loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstood the for each loop

Here and in the next loop

```
for(String element : kolom) 
            element = readText.next();
```

`element` does have the same memory location of `kolom[1],kolom[0] etc` so if you change the value of `element` it doesnot mean you change array at particular index.So the array is not initialized giving you null.

Instead you can use while loop

```
while(readText.hasNext()){

   kolom[i++]=scanner.nextLine();  //and so on for other array
}
```

Answer (score 1):

check out this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Data {
private String[][] data;
private String[] kolom;
    public Data() throws FileNotFoundException {
        data = new String[300][4];  
        kolom = new String[4];

        Scanner readLine = new Scanner(new File("E:/Data.txt"));
        Scanner readText = new Scanner(readLine.nextLine()).useDelimiter(";");

        int lineNumber = 0;
        while(readLine.hasNextLine()){
            String line = readLine.nextLine();
            kolom=line.split(";");   // filling data to kolom array
            data[lineNumber]=kolom;   // filling data to data array
            lineNumber++;
        }    


    }
    public String[] getKolom() {
        return kolom;
    }
    public String[][] getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException  {
        Data data = new Data();
        for(String element : data.getKolom()) 
            System.out.print(" "+element);

        System.out.println("\n*******data*********");
        for(String[] row : data.getData()) {
            for(String element : row)
                System.out.print(" "+element);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

problem with your code was you were not filling data in `kolom` and `data`